# Display Ajax DropDownExtender with another control

Tags: ajax, dropdownextender

Is it possible to display the Ajax DropDownExtender by clicking something else on the page?  Button, ImageButton, Anchor, Image, HyperLink, whatever.

---better explanation---

I have a textbox with a dropdownextender.  Works fine.  What I'd like to do is display that dropdownextender by clicking on another control.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how the `DropdownExtender` is intended to work.

However, there is a (somewhat imperfect) workaround.  Whatever control you'd like to click on (Button, ImageButton, Anchor, Image, HyperLink, etc.), assign it an "onclick" event that does this:

**Javascript**

```
function displayDropDownExtender() {
    // Get the TextBox control that your extender is currently linked to
    var junk = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>');
    // Call the DropDownBehavior.hover() method to display the hover effect
    junk.DropDownBehavior.hover();
    // Call the DropDownBehavior._showPopup() method to display the DropDown panel
    junk.DropDownBehavior._showPopup();
}
```

Comment: @Scott I just saw your update (wow, it's been a while) and realized my original answer wouldn't solve your problem.  I hope this one helps =)